# 4-layer PCB from Stackup manager but inner layers are not used

Tags: pcb, altium, pcb-fabrication

I am trying to arrange for fabrication of a design which is set up for 4 layers in Altium. But the 2 middle layers in this stack up are not used at all. In the generated Gerber files for these inner layers (*.G1 and *.G2), both files have a size of 1 kB.

When I sent it to the fabrication company (PCBway), it was mentioned to me that these files are not recognised at all and was asked if I only needed a 2-layer PCB. My stackup is described below:

[image: 4-layer stackup]

(This stackup is taken from the following template: https://s3.amazonaws.com/mfprodpublic/datasheets/MacroFab+Stackup+Report.pdf)

Would it be okay to just remove the 2 middle layers and go with a 2-layer PCB in this scenario? Or is there anything else I need to check other than knowing that no vias make use of the inner layers.

Comment: Most probably yes.

Comment: Seems OK. If I did this at work I would probably redo the files with a 2-layer stackup to not confuse other designers (or my future self).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can submit the job as 2 layers with the appropriate overall thickness.

As was mentioned, you could modify the Altium stackup to match what you really are doing, to avoid confusion down the road.

Answer (score 2):

Depends if you used controlled impedance.
In this case the 4-layer preset from Altium included Power Planes by default in inner layers. Altium 2D solver calculates the impedance based on spacing between outer and inner layers (0.23mm in your case). If you have controlled impedance traces then you will need to stick with 4 layers (or go for 2 layers but change the trace width for 50ohms). Then what you need to do after routing traces is to change the setting for the inner layer to "signal" in the stackup manager and place polygons associated to GND nets.

If you don't use any kind of high speed circuitry and you have a complete GND plane on bottom layer (without any tracks routed on) then you will be fine with 2 layers.